# Tinymce button arangement

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, textarea

The following is my code for my TinyMCE text area but I would like to edit the buttons shown into neat sections. I found some nicely formatted code below. Any ideas how I can duplicate the formatting (button grouping and rows) as the below code.

My code

```
<?php $content = ''; $editor_id = 'txtArea'; wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings = array(
       'editor_class'=>'ckeditor', 
       'media_buttons'=>false, 
       'quicktags'=>false, 
       'tinymce' => array( 
       'theme_advanced_buttons1' => ,
       'theme_advanced_buttons2' => ,
       'theme_advanced_buttons3' => ,
       'theme_advanced_buttons4' => ,
```

The Formatted code I found

```
   { name: 'format', items : [ 'Format','Font','FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors', items : [ 'TextColor','BGColor' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
    { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll'] },
    { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize'] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','CreateDiv',
    '-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'] },
    { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'source', items : [ 'Source'] }
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found my own answer because it seems to be working

```
    <?php $content = ''; $editor_id = 'txtArea'; wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings = array(
       'editor_class'=>'ckeditor', 
       'media_buttons'=>false, 
       'quicktags'=>false, 
       //'tinymce' => array( 
       //'theme_advanced_buttons1' =>'' ,
       //'theme_advanced_buttons2' =>'' ,
       //'theme_advanced_buttons3' =>'' ,
       //'theme_advanced_buttons4' =>'')
        ));?>
        <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace('txtArea', {toolbar:'Standard'});
        CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {    
    config.toolbar_Standard = [
        { name: 'format', items : [ 'Format','Font','FontSize' ] },
        { name: 'colors', items : [ 'TextColor','BGColor' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
        { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll'] },
        { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize'] },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','CreateDiv',
        '-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'] },
        { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
        { name: 'source', items : [ 'Source'] }
    ];

};
        </script>
```

It may not be the prettiest code in the world but as long as it works :)